# one website on 2 servers

Tags: linux, load-balancing, hosting, failover

i want to put my website on 2 servers, When server #1 is down, my site loads from server#2 . How can i do this? i want this 2 servers synced realtime...
is there any software for this? or any trick?
my servers is linux cent os

Comment: Pay someone to do it, by simply asking this here you are clearly out of your depth.

Comment: What sort of website do you have? Is it static files that can be put on two separate servers? Is there a database involved? Can users upload files? Do you already have the site up somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you're prepared to put in the work...

Put a load balancer (e.g. nginx) in front of your 2 web servers and have your 2 web servers share some kind of central storage like an NFS mount or a cluster file system like OCFS2.

Of course the devil is in the details but that should get you started. Acknowledge that you're going to spend a lot of time investigating and testing before you do this in production or like Chopper3 said in his comment you should consider hiring someone to do it for you.